# Why await is not working in async function?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

I know this question is more about asynchronous programming but why

```js
    async function func2(){
       var result=await (1+1);
       console.log(result);
    }
    (async ()=>{
       var result=await (1+1);
       console.log(result);
       func2();
       while(true)
       {}
    })();
```

this code is not working(output:2 and infinity waiting)
whereas

```
async function func2(){`
   var result=await (1+1);`
   console.log(result);
}
(async ()=>{
   var result=await (1+1);
   console.log(result);
   func2();
   while(true)
   {
      await (1+1);          
    }
})();
```

this code work(output:2 2)

Comment: [await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) does not make code asynchronous -> "Returns the fulfilled value of the promise, or the value itself if it's not a Promise"

Comment: It also probably does not help to have that `while (true) {}` there. Spin-waits are bad.